# ¿Como hacer un piedra, papel o tijera con punteros?

Tags: c, dev-c++

El problema trata sobre realizar una funcion que reciba dos punteros char y dos valores char en los cuales los punteros representan a los jugadores y los valores char a el valor elejido lso cuales son: "p" para piedra, "h" para papel y "t" para tijera. La funcion debe decidir quien gana e infromarlos en los punteros a los jugadores con "w" para el que gane  y "l" para el perdedro y por ultimo la funcion main debe de imprimir los resultados.

¿La pregunta es todo esto como puedo evitar que me salte el error de char to char asignarles los valores en main en la funcion?

Esto es lo que pude avanzar del codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void juego(char *n1, char *n2, char nm1, char nm2)
{   
char win[] = "win";
char lost[] = "Lost";
 
if((nm1 == 'h') && (nm2 == 'p'))
{
    n1 = win;
    n2 = lost;  
    printf("\nJugador2 %c y jugador1 %c", *n2, *n1);    
} 
else if ((nm2 == 'h') && (nm1 == 'p'))
  {
    n1 = lost;
    n2 = win;   
    printf("\nJugador2 %c y jugador1 %c", *n2, *n1);
  } 
else if ((nm1 == 'p') && (nm2 == 't'))
  {
    n1 = win;
    n2 = lost;  
    printf("\nJugador2 %c y jugador1 %c", *n2, *n1);        
  }
else if ((nm2 == 'p') && (nm1 == 't'))
  {
    n1 = lost;
    n2 = win;   
    printf("\nJugador2 %c y jugador1 %c", *n2, *n1);        
  }
else if ((nm1 == 't') && (nm2 == 'h'))
  {
    n1 = win;
    n2 = lost;  
    printf("\nJugador2 %c y jugador1 %c", *n2, *n1);        
  }
else if ((nm2 == 't') && (nm1 == 'h'))
  {
    n1 = lost;
    n2 = win;   
    printf("\nJugador2 %c y jugador1 %c", *n2, *n1);        
  }
else if (nm2 == nm1)
  {
     printf("Empate");      
  }
 }

 int main()
 {   
 char *n1[5];
 char *n2[5];
 char nm1[1];
 char nm2[1];

 printf("Elija p = piedra, h = papel o t = tijera: ");
 scanf("%d", &nm1);

 printf("\nElija jugador2 p = piedra, h = papel o t = tijera: ");
 scanf("%d", &nm2);

 juego(n1, n2, nm1, nm2);
 }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Modifique el codigo y depaso le puse la pregunta.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "*el error de char to char*"?

Comment: Me refiero que en el prototipo de funcion lo tengo como puntero *char y en main lo tengo que definir devuelta para poder implementarlo en la funcion y lo defino como char en main el problema surge en que me salta el erorr de no se puede convertir un *char a char

Answer (score 1):

Nada más leer tu código se ven fallos evidentes:

- Usa nombres auto-explicativos para saber qué hace cada variable. Puede que ahora mismo sepas lo que hace cada parte de tu código, pero si re-lees tu propio código pasado un tiempo te costará mucho entenderlo.

  En lugar de esto:

  ```
  char *n1[5];
  char *n2[5];
  char nm1[1];
  char nm2[1];
  ```

  Usa esto:

  ```
  char *jugador_1[5];
  char *jugador_2[5];
  char jugada_1[1];
  char jugada_2[1];
  ```
- En [c](/questions/tagged/c) las cadenas de caracteres se guardan en formaciones<sup>1</sup> de caracteres, que son `char formacion[tamaño];` en cambio tú has definido `char *formacion[tamaño]` que no es una formación de caracteres si no una formación de punteros a carácter.

  En lugar de esto:

  ```
  char *jugador_1[5];
  char *jugador_2[5];
  char jugada_1[1];
  char jugada_2[1];
  ```

  Usa esto:

  ```
  char jugador_1[5];
  char jugador_2[5];
  char jugada_1[1];
  char jugada_2[1];
  ```

  Ten en cuenta que una cadena de texto de cinco caracteres sólo puede almacenar hasta cuatro letras (pues se necesita un carácter para guardar la marca de final de cadena: `'\0'`), yo incrementaría el tamaño de las formaciones que guardan el nombre de cada jugador.
- No necesitas una formación de un carácter para almacenar un carácter; usa directamente una variable de tipo `char`.

  En lugar de esto:

  ```
  char jugador_1[5];
  char jugador_2[5];
  char jugada_1[1];
  char jugada_2[1];
  ```

  Usa esto:

  ```
  char jugador_1[25];
  char jugador_2[25];
  char jugada_1;
  char jugada_2;
  ```
- Para leer un carácter con la función de lectura desde consola `scanf` debes usar `%c`, si usas `%d` estarás leyendo números.

  En lugar de esto:

  ```
  char jugador_1[25];
  char jugador_2[25];
  char jugada_1[1];
  char jugada_2[1];

  printf("Elija p = piedra, h = papel o t = tijera: ");
  scanf("%d", &nm1);

  printf("\nElija jugador2 p = piedra, h = papel o t = tijera: ");
  scanf("%d", &nm2);
  ```

  Usa esto:

  ```
  char jugador_1[25];
  char jugador_2[25];
  char jugada_1;
  char jugada_2;

  printf("Jugador %s: Elija p = piedra, h = papel o t = tijera: ", jugador_1);
  scanf("%c", &jugada_1);

  printf("Jugador %s: Elija p = piedra, h = papel o t = tijera: ", jugador_2);
  scanf("%c", &jugada_2);
  ```
- Defines la función `juego` para recibir dos punteros a carácter y dos caracteres, pero le provees dos punteros a puntero a carácter y dos punteros a carácter, esto provoca el error que describes.

  En lugar de esto:

  ```
  char *n1[5];
  char *n2[5];
  char nm1[1];
  char nm2[1];

  // ...

  juego(n1, n2, nm1, nm2);
  ```

  Usa esto:

  ```
  char jugador_1[25];
  char jugador_2[25];
  char jugada_1;
  char jugada_2;

  // ...

  juego(jugador_1, jugador_2, jugada_1, jugada_2);
  ```
- En lugar de una larga cadena de `if-else-if` para definir la lógica de Piedra, Papel y Tijera, usa una tabla de resultados:

  ```
  // 0 empate, 1 ganar, -1 perder
  int resultado[3][3] = {
                  // Piedra | Papel | Tijera
  /* Piedra vs */ {    0,      -1,      1   },
  /* Papel  vs */ {    1,       0,     -1   },
  /* Tijera vs */ {   -1,       1,      0   } };
  ```

Siguiendo todos esos consejos tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void juego(char *jugador_1, char *jugador_2, char jugada_1, char jugada_2)
{
    // 0 empate, 1 ganar, -1 perder
    int resultado[3][3] = {
                        // Piedra | Papel | Tijera
        /* Piedra vs */ {    0,      -1,      1   },
        /* Papel  vs */ {    1,       0,     -1   },
        /* Tijera vs */ {   -1,       1,      0   } };

    int indice1 =
        (jugada_1 == 'p' ? 0 :
            (jugada_1 == 'h' ? 1 :
                (jugada_1 == 't' ? 2 : -1)));

    int indice2 =
        (jugada_2 == 'p' ? 0 :
            (jugada_2 == 'h' ? 1 :
                (jugada_2 == 't' ? 2 : -1)));

    if (indice1 == -1 || indice2 == -1)
    {
        printf("Jugada incorrecta");
        return;
    }

    switch (resultado[indice1][indice2])
    {
        case -1: printf("%s pierde\n", jugador_1); break;
        case 0: printf("%s y %s empatan\n", jugador_1, jugador_2); break;
        case 1: printf("%s pierde\n", jugador_2); break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char jugador_1[] = "Sigerico";
    char jugador_2[] = "Chindasvinta";
    char jugada_1;
    char jugada_2;

    printf("Jugador %s: Elija p = piedra, h = papel o t = tijera: ", jugador_1);
    scanf("%c", &jugada_1);
    getchar();

    printf("Jugador %s: Elija p = piedra, h = papel o t = tijera: ", jugador_2);
    scanf("%c", &jugada_2);
    getchar();

    juego(jugador_1, jugador_2, jugada_1, jugada_2);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRNj5swED3jXzGiShci0oB7g9Ieql56Wqm9baLKNV5wmgVkTKpqw29Px3yT3aiXWkkY@828x3hmwjcp55fLG5nzY50I@FDpRBbvso@EnAqZwKEWaeHwjClYH@qUJYX6EXiwPKD9QbtnI95vqUueibXdgg/iqWRaeBBAynKmPNgEUAqVCEUsmWtQoqqPGjkf3u/xAzFgJC4MvpciUQzOcM9KccTnd3kQiiG8XQ/gqYL1Fp4Bl@9BuzZBbwT4bbzevaWYuw9eQ9xm7t4pzdxH0jHON@7QRKTLQ@aJ5CKAGAmc4VYgjuGuvINP6B2atJZIZpCgQ64gbSAKIQq7rrsUoQsRelOE3hahr4uUClUeHXuX7/SKwyrxoH3sctublbrPdTyiwxHt3vQRnPE6YnOx5/P06ubAJZap8iD3taVBF14oJbhmNvJYlhK6VjlaDZJWv6XmGThTv/QS@96g@56Vs0qgRggD/aqCUpqWm9IwLe1G8FMJ9isaYvxFyB/An7Z7Wb4MnEz6guOfsvOQhmBmpq5PTOZOOzPTFBmlBzMP9jeZCiV5YUdXOO3wzxneAKtOyMSWPlitqz01BVrce6Ew0RC@HOWBQYl8ZTtZHmTGbsemAI22bmcihOUdYmU4y026HIG3g6wBUqGNtOP@V016S5O@0Oz@yV6r27ybZ@Gk7znwI9JcLiXR5C8)</kbd>.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Gracias por los conocimientos.

Comment: Lo mejor del primer punto es que creas código que se "explica solo". Por lo tanto necesitarás menos o incluso ningún comentario en tu código para que se entienda.